# Web activity throws overlimit error when calling rest api

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My ADF pipeline has a lookup activity which uses a sql query to get data from a table and passes it to a web activity which posts the JSON to an API (azure app service). When the query gets 1000 rows it works fine but when I try over 5000 rows the web activity returns the error.

```
"errorCode": "2001",
"message": "The length of execution ouput is over limit (around 1M currently). ",
"failureType": "UserError",
```

When I post the 5000 rows to the API using postman it works fine. Any idea what this error means and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found, web activity has times out limitation for 1 minute. Also, based on the above error `The length of execution output is over limit (around 1M currently).`, web activity also has output size limitation for 1 MB.

You could find the limitation rules [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#data-factory-limits) and some of the them could be adjusted if you ask for [Contact Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-limits-quotas-increase-requests/).

If nothing they can do,I provide you with a workaround that you could use [ForEach Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity). Maybe you need to use `paging query` for your rest api and return a limited number of the data each time. Then query your data in loop until the number of return data is lower than threshold value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the web activity times out after 1 minute if the endpoint its calling doesn't respond.

[image]