# The length of execution ouput is over limit (around 1M currently) in azure adf webactivity rest api

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Calling azure rest api (/consumption/usagedetails) in webactivity using azure data factory .It throws error The length of execution output is over limit (around 1M currently).Any suggestion

Comment: Hi Shipra Nigam,If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Please reference this blog: [Web activity throws overlimit error when calling rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843154/web-activity-throws-overlimit-error-when-calling-rest-api), Jay Gong has given the answer.

Web activity has times out limitation for 1 minute. Also, based on the above error `The length of execution ouput is over limit (around 1M currently).`, web activity also has output size limitation for 1 MB.

You could find the limitation rules from [Data Factory limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#data-factory-limits) and some of the them could be adjusted if you ask for [Contact Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-limits-quotas-increase-requests/).

According the Data Factory limits and your data size, choose the right Azure Data Factory component. Such as Yuvarajan said: You can create a HTTP link service and HTTP data set and pull the data from REST API.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Web activity has  limitation of output size of 1 MB. You can create a HTTP link service and
HTTP data set and pull the data from REST API.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later (or SQL Managed Instance), you can use python to do this instead. Recommend to use Postman to generate the python script. As an additional extra, you can use the openjson function to convert turn this into tabular format too.

```
DECLARE @response NVARCHAR(MAX)

EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python'
    , @script = N'

import requests
import json

url = "https://..................................."

payload = json.dumps({
  "api_key": "............................"
})
headers = {
  ''Subscription-Key'': ''.........................'',
  ''Content-Type'': ''application/json'',
  ''Ocp-Apim-Trace'': ''false''
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
response = response.text
'
,@params = N'@response NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'
,@response=@response OUTPUT

INSERT INTO dbo.mytable ([response])
SELECT @response
```