# "The length of execution output is over limit" Error in ADF Web Activity

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-factory

I am getting the following error in my ADF Web Activity. Anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks!

```
 activity failures
{
    "errorCode": "2001",
    "message": "The length of execution output is over limit (around 1M currently). ",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "ADFGetEmployees",
    "details": []
}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876302/the-length-of-execution-ouput-is-over-limit-around-1m-currently-in-azure-adf-w

Comment: Hello Mike, If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web activity has times out limitation for 1 minute. Also, based on the above error `The length of execution ouput is over limit (around 1M currently)`., web activity also has output size limitation for 1 MB.

You could find the limitation rules from [Data Factory limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#data-factory-limits) and some of the them could be adjusted if you ask for [Contact Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-limits-quotas-increase-requests/).

According the Data Factory limits and your data size, some workaround is that choose the right Azure Data Factory component. Such as: [HTTP connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http), the [REST connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest) and the [Web table connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-web-table):
[image]

Ref: [Web activity throws overlimit error when calling rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843154/web-activity-throws-overlimit-error-when-calling-rest-api)