# Stored procedure on azure data factory is failing with error message : The length of execution output is over limit (around 1M currently)

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I am running this stored procedure on azure data factory. The stored procedure perform some computation on 10 millions rows and takes about 90 minutes (Yup. I know I need to profile it). This stored procedure is working fine when I run it from SSMS but when triggering or debugging it on the data factory it throws this error:

> "errorCode": "2001",
>   "message": "The length of execution output is over limit (around 1M currently). ",
>   "failureType": "UserError",
>   "target": "Booking Flattening",

Is it a configuration issue ? Any pointers you have would be greatly helpful.
I am running azure data factory version 2 and SQL Server 2014 on Azure

Comment: As you are running traditional SQL Server as Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS), (sometimes called 'box product') in Azure, you could consider running your stored procedure via a SQL Agent job rather than Azure Data Factory (ADF).  Would that work for you?  An Agent job would not time out.  Also consider posting the stored procedure and execution plan as a separate question for some performance tuning tips.

Comment: Hi eAlie, If my answer is helpful for you, can you please accept(mark) it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reference this GitHub blog:[The length of execution output is over limit (around 1M currently), Azure Data Factory #40088](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/40088).

Azure MSFT said: "There currently is bug with handling very large monitoring outputs".

Actually, as I searched a lot, not only Stored Procedure has the "The length of execution output is over limit (around 1M currently)." error, other actives also have the same error, such as Function, Data Flow, Lookup and so on.

We don't know when Data Factory product team will solve the Data Factory output limitation.

Someone has post the question in Data Factory feedback, and it's voted up 18 times. But still has no reply. Please see here:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/37843276-remove-output-limitations-on-web-and-azure-function

Most suggestions are using the [For-Each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) active to help you avoid the output limit error.

Reference: [Web activity throws overlimit error when calling rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843154/web-activity-throws-overlimit-error-when-calling-rest-api)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Leon. Now, I am looking into the workarounds to suppress any kind of execution output/logs/error messages for my stored procedure in order to make it runnable on adf. I think try catch will help me capture that