# Azure Data Factory Pipeline - Web Activity - maximize the length of execution output size

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have tried to get data from API which returns 8 MB response data.
I have created Azure Data Factory pipeline and used web activity to get API response data. When I run the pipeline after configuring it, it returns [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks5pK.png)  "The length of execution output is over limit (around 4MB currently)"

Can any one help me with that how can I handle large size response data in web activity?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to use [ForEach activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity), you need to use paging query for your rest api and return a limited number of the data each time. Then query your data in loop until the number of return data is lower than threshold value.

Source - [Web activity throws overlimit error when calling rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843154/web-activity-throws-overlimit-error-when-calling-rest-api)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm using that REST API which doesn't contain paging so it returns large amount of data everytime and I have to handle it at my end only as in AAD web activity or anything else in AAD